# how do I reset counter to start over running a function?

Tags: javascript, counter, reset

I'm trying to run a js function 10 times, and then reset the counter to start over. However, what I get with the following code is an unlimited execution of the function. It looks like the counter variable is reset to 1 at the "else" portion of the code (resulting in a hiccup during running it), and then it runs again starting from 1. However, what I need is to stop the function at "row_count = 10", and the start over at the next trial (this is an ibex farm experiment, btw). Can anyone help me fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
row_count = 1;
function CreateWordRows() {
        if (row_count < 10) {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='userInput' 
    onkeypress='EnterFunc(event);MoveFocus(event)' style='font-size:20px;color:blue'>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='number' id='percentage' min='10' max='100' style='font- 
    size:20px;color:blue' disabled>";
    row_count += 1;
    } else {       
       userInput.disabled = true;        
       percentage.disabled = true;
       row_count = 1   
    }     
}
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Since you equate row_count = 1 in the else part, there is an endless loop

Comment: @Django There is nothing in the code here to indicate that it should repeat at all.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass I'm running this code in "Ibex Farm" which is platform for running experiments (which makes things complicated). You can run the experiment here: https://spellout.net/ibexexps/HosseinKarimi/Ent_Pred_Cloze/experiment.html

Comment: @Django Thanks for your reply. If I do not add the row_count =1 part, the code stops at the 11th trial.

Answer (score 0):

```
  row_count = 1;
    function CreateWordRows(row_count) {
        if (row_count < 10) {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='userInput' 
    onkeypress='EnterFunc(event);MoveFocus(event)' style='font-size:20px;color:blue'>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='number' id='percentage' min='10' max='100' style='font- 
    size:20px;color:blue' disabled>";
    row_count += 1;
    } else {       
       userInput.disabled = true;        
       percentage.disabled = true; 
    }     
}    

CreateWordRows(row_count)
```

you can use this so row_count = 1 no need to sync
You don't need to set the variable to one as the variable will be incremented inside the function block.

sorry for bad english:)

Answer (score -1):

**This is the minimal code you need to follow to achieve it:**

```js
let row_count = 1;

function CreateWordRows() {
  if (row_count < 10) {
    console.log(`counter ${row_count}`);
    row_count += 1;
    CreateWordRows();
  }

  if (row_count >= 10) row_count = 1;
}

CreateWordRows();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually ended up not using a counter. I just added a limit to the number of rows created by CreateWordRows().